# TokenMismatchException when trying to use media-upload

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and the media-upload package for ajax image uploads.

https://github.com/triasrahman/laravel-media-upload

Using the following code:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
<img clas="preview" src="">

$('input[name=file]').change(function()
{   
    // AJAX Request
    $.post( 'media-upload', {file: $(this).val()} )
        .done(function( data )
        {
            if(data.error)
            {
                // Log the error
                console.log(error);
            }
            else
            {
                // Change the image attribute
                $( 'img.preview' ).attr( 'src', data.path );
            }
        });
});
```

I get an 500 internal server error.

Exactly matches this issue:

https://github.com/triasrahman/laravel-media-upload/issues/1

But I'm not fully understanding how to get mine to work. I did do the same code as the answer added. I still get the 500 error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post your whole form?

Answer (score 0):

As in the link from github says, you must pass the token.
 `_token : $("[name='_token']").val()`

```
<input type="file" name="file">
<img clas="preview" src="">

$('input[name=file]').change(function()
{   
    // AJAX Request
    $.post( 'media-upload', {file: $(this).val(), _token : $("[name='_token']").val()} )
        .done(function( data )
        {
            if(data.error)
            {
                // Log the error
                console.log(error);
            }
            else
            {
                // Change the image attribute
                $( 'img.preview' ).attr( 'src', data.path );
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add it this way if you are submitting form via ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers : {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```